# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```sql
    ALTER PROCEDURE Dashbord @userid INT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @reportmanager INT 
      DECLARE @admintype INT 

      SET @reportmanager = (SELECT Count(managerid) 
                            FROM   reportingperson 
                            WHERE  employeeid = @userid) 
      SET @admintype = (SELECT Max(admintype) 
                        FROM   employee 
                        WHERE  content_id = @userid) 

      IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 WHERE  @reportmanager > 0 
                        AND @admintype = 0) 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT b.contentid, 
                   x.content_id, 
                   x.employeename, 
                   x.imagetype, 
                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.fromdate, 126)    AS fromdate, 
                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.todate, 126)      AS Todate, 
                   b.leaveapp, 
                   b.leavesubject, 
                   b.reason, 
                   ( CASE 
                       WHEN ( b.status = 0 ) THEN 'Pending' 
                       ELSE 'Approved' 
                     END )                                  AS status, 
                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.createddate, 126) AS Createddate 
            FROM   leaves b 
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN employee x 
                                ON b.employeeid = x.content_id 
            WHERE  ( b.employeeid = @userid ) 
                   AND b.status = 0 

            SELECT admintype 
            FROM   employee 
            WHERE  content_id = @userid 
        END 
      ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT b.contentid, 
                   x.content_id, 
                   x.employeename, 
                   x.imagetype, 
                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.fromdate, 126)    AS fromdate, 
                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.todate, 126)      AS Todate, 
                   b.leaveapp, 
                   b.leavesubject, 
                   b.reason, 
                   ( CASE 
                       WHEN ( b.status = 0 ) THEN 'Pending' 
                       ELSE 'Approved' 
                     END )                                  AS status, 
                   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.createddate, 126) AS Createddate 
            FROM   leaves b 
                   LEFT OUTER JOIN employee x 
                                ON b.employeeid = x.content_id 
            WHERE  b.employeeid IN (SELECT employeeid 
                                    FROM   reportingperson 
                                    WHERE  managerid = @userid) 
                   AND b.status = 0 

            SELECT admintype 
            FROM   employee 
            WHERE  content_id = @userid 
        END 
  END
```

I have to now once the person have approved the leave the notification has to go to the another reporting person then approve the leave and then employee can go to this house

Comment: Add `select top 1 ...` to the inner query. no need to paste the whole filesystem.

Comment: Also, remove commented code.  It makes it difficult to read what is relevant and what is not.

Comment: why `downvoting` better do something that will contribute something to  society , Tell `OP` how to ask questions not `downvote`.

Comment: I downvoted because this is a bad way to ask a question. It should be very easy for the OP to see exactly which part of the query is failing, but virtually impossible for anyone else. Also, I suspect that the cause of the error is not actually part of the posted code. I looked at the subqueries in the SQL in the question, and I don't see any that could possibly return more than one value, except one that follows `exists` and one that follows `in` (where it's okay).

Answer (score 0):

**I recommend that you take each query, and subquery, and test it on its own until you detect the one that is causing problems**

Also in this part of the query...

```
left outer join employee x on b.employeeid=x.content_id
where (b.employeeid=@userid 
) and b.status=0
```

if you are doing a join `on b.employeeid=x.content_id` why do you then add a WHERE `b.employeeid=@userid` both conditions are checking against the same field `b.employeeid` that might be causing some unexpected behavior

Comment: take each query, and subquery, and test it on its own until you detect the one that is causing problems

Comment: now i want send the notification the reporting person and to another reporting person. if the notification accept then the notification has the higher reporting person

Comment: hello anybody is there

Comment: Did you solve the problem ? if that is the case post the answer and if you need more help please post a new question

Comment: @sonuods this page is oriented to solve problems one by one, maybe you can ask a friend or colleage for some help with all your topics